# How do I move avi files from a folder and its subfolders?

Tags: batch-file, move

I'm trying to move all avi files of a folder and its subfolders to another folder.
Here is my first try in batch but it's a bit hard compared to bash :

  `cd %1
  path=%cd%
  for /r path %f in (*.avi) do @move *.avi path`

For example :

```
Folder 1
SubFolder1
   FileX.avi
   FileA.txt
SubFolder2
    FileY.avi
    FileB.txt
SubFolder3
    FileZ.avi
    FileC.txt
```

I want to put FileX FileY FileZ into Folder1 (or another specified path).

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

the FOR with /R option is the correct approach. you only need to change it like so:

```
set source=sourcepath
set target=targetpath

for /r %source% %f in (*.avi) do move %f %target%
```

Make sure that the target path is NOT a subfolder of the sourcepath and there are no duplicate file names. 
If you want this for a cmd-file you need to change %f to %%f

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this batch code :

```
@echo off
set "Source=SourcePath"
set "Target=TargetPatch""
::Just to echo the action while moving files
for /r %Source% %%f in (*.avi) do echo move "%%f" "%target%"
:: Moving Files
for /r %source% %%f in (*.avi) do move "%%f" "%target%"
pause
```